# How to create a Distributed Ledger

Tags: blockchain

I'm new to Blockchain but I do understand the concept behind it. My question is can we only contribute to blockchain through chaincodes or can we also create a distributed ledger? And also where does the Ledger gets stored?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to implement a distributed ledger, blockchain is one way, but there are many new and exciting alternatives.

For example (prior art), Amandla-3i-Backbone uses an architecture where agents execute on a host. Essentially, a transaction is committed in just over 10 steps.
Amandla-3i-Ecosystem

Step 1

An arbitrary Agent decides to make a transaction. This Agent can be embedded in any product, such as an Android mobile application.

In this example, the application is transferring money to another user.

What is not shown in this step is that the Agent would need to locate a suitable Trade-Agent to conduct the transaction. This could be hardwired into the application, or it could have access to another Trust-Agent that could forward the details of a reputable Trade-Agent.

Step 2

The Agent describes the transaction it wants to the Trade-Agent which will conduct the complex workflow on behalf of the Agent requesting the transaction.

Note that the Agent is renting processing power from it’s local Node, and will be charged by the Trade-Agent for all work done. This monitisation means that economic type attacks are not possible.

The first thing the Trade-Agent does is contact the Buyer-Brokering-Agent directly.

It’s important to note that the Buyer and Seller do not interact directly, because Trust-Agents need to witness each transaction so that Brokering-Agent don’t oversell their currency at a high rate of exchange. An analogy would be a government printing too much money. It would be the Trust-Agents that would need to signal a devaluation in the appropriate Brokering-Agent currency if they witnessed this economic theft from taking place.

Step 3

Just after informing the Buyer-Brokering-Agent of the upcoming transaction, the Trade-Agent connects with a number of Trust-Agents that will witness the transaction. This could be a high number (possibly as much as 7 or more) of Trust-Agents. It is in the interest of the Trade-Agent to authenticate this transaction with a high degree of trust in order for the Trade-Agent to maintain its credibility on the network, since it is also rated by other Trust-Agents. It is likely to choose agents that have verified their execution and code to ensure there is no cheating. Only 2 Trust-Agents are shown on the diagram for descriptive purposes.

Step 4

The Trust-Agents begin the chaperoned trade by connecting to the same Buyer-Brokering-Agent and present the trade that they intend to witness.

Step 5

In the meantime, the original Trade-Agent connects to the seller and establishes the upcoming trade.

Step 6

Also simultaneously, the Trust-Agent also connects with the Seller-Brokering-Agent and signals their role as witness.

Step 7

Once the Seller-Brokering-Agent is informed of the transaction, it also makes a connection directly with the Buyer-Brokering-Agent and performs the chaperoned transaction.

Step 8A and Step 8B

Both the Buyer-Brokering-Agent and the Seller-Brokering-Agent connect to each of the Trust-Agents that are witnessing the transaction as part of the authentication process.

Step 9

The Trust-Agents confirm that the transaction was successful.

Step 10

The Trade-Agent completes the transaction.

[Distributed Ledger Transaction Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDefm.png)

Example call

[Sample call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfnUq.png)

Answer (score 0):

*note: I'm not an expert, I'm a student.*

a ledger is composed of the data in the blocks of your blockchain. the schema of the ledger is agreed upon in advance (in the protocol of the blockchain), and trust is assured through the design of the ledger, mechanics of the blockchain, and often the proof of work in writing the next block.

blockchains don't need to be multi-party, they only need to be multi-party to be very useful. blockchains can be distributed by utilizing the network layer, with an eye to scale and trust: a large number of participants or important work should require good proof of work and/or other security measures. Trust can even be ensured by giving certain parties higher rights than others, but this is more useful in industrial uses than in digital currencies.

an example of a network solution that is suitable (but cumbersome) to use for custom blockchains is peerJS (I'm fairly sure it is sufficient). In essence though, the entire thing can be written over connections such as webRTC or raw network connections.

an alternative to writing all of this yourself is to use a general purpose ledger with composable contracts, like etherium or IBM's hyperledger. However, I would argue this is less than ideal for learning about the technology.